# PlatformIO ATMega324P util/delay.h not accurate

Tags: c++, microcontroller, atmega, platformio

I am using PlatformIO and CLion to program an ATMega324P Microcontroller. The project is created with PlatformIO on a mac and opened in CLion. I can successfully build the program and run it on the ATMega324p. I run the following code successfully.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{
    DDRB |= 1 << PINB0; 

    while (true)
    {
        PORTB ^= 1 << PINB0; 
        _delay_ms(100);
    }
}
```

**Platformio.ini**

```
[env:mightycore324]
platform = atmelavr
board = mightycore324
framework = arduino
upload_protocol = usbtiny
board_f_cpu = 16000000L
```

Although this code run the delay seems noticeably inaccurate. Do I have do anything to make sure the delay is working properly?

Comment: Where did you define F_CPU?

Comment: @DavidGrayson I defined it in the Platformio.ini (see edit above)

Comment: @DavidGrayson are you suggesting there is another possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MCU is probably running off its internal RC oscillator. This oscillator isn't particularly precise -- it's specified as 8 MHz, but individual parts may run anywhere from 7.3 to 8.1 MHz.

To get more accurate timing, you'll need to attach an external crystal and program the clock fuses accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The following settings fixed my issue.

**Platformio.ini**

```
[env:mightycore324]
platform = atmelavr
board = mightycore324
framework = arduino
upload_protocol = usbtiny
board_f_cpu = 800000L
```

Comment: It would have helped if you'd mentioned the delay was half of what it was supposed to be! "Noticeably inaccurate" is what you say when it's off by maybe 10% -- not 100%.

Comment: @duskwuff my apologies. You help was appreciated.